# Глюки в отображении HTML

Tags: html

Есть сайт, который написан на Django. Но на компе у заказчика страницы периодически отображаются таким образом, что часть тегов показана в виде текста, как на картинках.

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]

Мне ни разу не удалось повторить этот глюк у себя, у заказчика он воспроизводится в разных браузерах.

Что это может быть?

**UPD.** Похоже, причина выяснена. Скорее всего заказчик подцепил вирус, который в конец страницы добавляет код:

```
<script src="%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20_%202-3-4-5_1.net_files/loader_alza.js"></script>
<iframe style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20_%202-3-4-5_1.net_files/cache.htm" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
<iframe name="dpmsi" style="position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;left:-1000px;top:-1000px;" src="%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20_%202-3-4-5_1.net_files/if.html
</iframe>
```

Comment: А html код страницы при таком глюке заказчик вам не показывает?

Comment: Пока еще я этот код не видел, но я попросил сохранить страницу в таком виде и прислать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не подгружаются css стили - на лицо. Если у вас всё впорядке на продакшене, а у клиента отпадают стили, то думаю стоит смотреть ПК пользователя, проблемы могут быть где угодно: интернет провайдер, вредоносное ПО на компьютере, сам браузер (как вариант какое то расширение).

Comment: Я боюсь, что тут дело не в CSS, там похоже, корежится HTML. А вот почему - вопрос.

Comment: Я же говорю, код может корежиться из-за вирусняковых расширений в браузере, не помню, как там называется вирусняк, когда много рекламы вылетает по верх страницы. А на чём работает сайт, всмысле CMS, самопис, или может какой нибудь node.js?

Comment: Сегодня получил код страницы от заказчика. Похоже, он действительно подцепил вирус. В конце добавляется какой-то левый скрипт с iframe. Сейчас обновлю вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

1.Если закажчик розместил страницу на сервер то можна проверить написание тегов через клавишу F12
После того во вкладке Elements будет показивать код общей страницы (страницы которая видна всем пользователям, которые заходят на сайт)
Тогда дойти к елементам на странице и проверить текст

2.Можно по тексту нажать ПКМ и вибрать "Просмотр кода елемента"
И выделяется текст кода который нужно проверить
(Работает только если не установление права страницы(не отключено копирование))

Comment: Страницы генерятся на сервере скриптом, но в скольких браузерах я не пробовал, в том числе и на разных компах, такого глюка поймать не удается.

Comment: А есть ссилка на сайт?

Comment: Да, сайт еще пока в процессе разработки, но уже работает - http://2-3-4-5.net/article/linguistics/english/learning/vocabulary/volume1/